Disabling an input when editing a record using AutoQuery and AutoQueryGrid
I want to disable or set to read-only an input when I am updating a record using AutoQuery and AutoQueryGrid, I have used the class attribute and also the property attribute and in no case it works, in the case of the property attribute I set it in the creation class and it works.
Creating it works
[Field(nameof(RegistrationDate), Disabled = true)]
[Field(nameof(InactiveDate), Disabled = true)]

public class CreateProduct : ICreateDb<Product>, IReturn<IdResponse>
{
...
}

Updating does not work
[Field(nameof(RegistrationDate), Disabled = true)]
[Field(nameof(InactiveDate), Disabled = true)]
public class UpdateProduct : IPatchDb<Product>, IReturn<IdResponse>
{
...
}

Am I doing something wrong, or is it designed like this?
Thanks!

You would use the [Input] attribute to modify the forms HTML Input attribute, e.g:
public class UpdateProduct : IPatchDb<Product>, IReturn<IdResponse>
{
    [Input(ReadOnly = true)]
    public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [Input(ReadOnly = true)]
    public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
}


Adding the property decoration as you showed does not disable the field in the user interface. I am using the Blazor-vue template with AutoQuery and AutoQueryGrid.
Thanks.

That should make it readonly, Use [Input(Disabled = true)] instead to disable it or [Input(Type = "hidden")] to hide it.

Adding the property decoration with disabled, readonly does not disable the field in the UI in the update service. Adding the property decoration with hidden does hide the element from the UI, but it is not the behavior we need for the UI when updating, we need the user to be able to see the value of the property, but not to be able to modify it. The strange thing is that decorating the properties with disabled in the create service, disables it. It works for create but not for update.

@AlmircarMontilla Not sure of the behavior you're seeing as this is working for me in Update Forms.
